# Storing data on txt file instead of creating a server for android app

Tags: android, json, httprequest, server-side

I have the following question, which I havn't succeeded on finding an answer.

I have a small amount of data on my app (a list of items) which i want to change from time to time. I have been using google app engine to create a server, and store the information there. Then used http requests to call the data from there, getting a json response then converting it to display in my app .

I can receive the same result, by saving the json "skeleton" as a .txt file, and store it someone online with a link, then my app get the response from that link. Then when I change some data, I just change it in the txt file.

Is this OK or incorrect practice? Will appreciate any advice. Thanks

Comment: Why no use online database?

Comment: I just thought for the small amount of infomation and changing, its easier.

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to maintain a checksum for the data, if the list of item is huge, as that would save you from undue updation your txt file. You can send that Checksum in the request and can see if the data at the link has a different checksum, send the son in response else just send a code to signify nothing has changed. This will also save you data.

Comment: Do you mean to still use a txt file, just use a checksum to see if it has been changed, to avoid unnecessary downloading again?

Comment: Yes, as you said its a small data. 
Why bother with database overhead.